# Does Rust expose call stack depth?

Tags: recursion, rust, callstack

Background information: I have a function that calls itself both directly and indirectly through other functions, and would like a cheap way to fail gracefully should the program run out of call stack. I could count calls manually, but I would like a more elegant and robust way of achieving this.

Is it possible to determine current call stack depth using stable Rust?

The only options I could find are:

1. Following the stack in ASM, but it requires unstable and is not portable.
2. Using a GNU libc extension (backtrace). However, backtrace is too wasteful and also not standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [stacker](https://crates.io/crates/stacker/) crate seems to provide the functionality you seek:

- A function to guarantee the amount of available stack
- A function to query the amount of remaining stack, which you could use to bail before the program actually stack-overflows

The library supports the Linux, Windows and macOS targets.

Comment: I have a few concerns about the crate's health given the severity of the sole open issue on github, but it does seem to provide what I need. Hope this functionality gets merged into the stdlib like glibc.

Comment: According to [this comment by the crates's owner and one of the main rustc's dev](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1488#issuecomment-179334635) this wouldn't be moved to the standard library. However, [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/41884) indicates this crate has a good future ahead.

Comment: I certainly hope so given how critical this issue is for reliable system software. Thanks for the info.