# How to get the current stack frame depth in Rust?

Tags: rust

How do I determine the current stack frame depth?

```rust
fn print_depths() {
    println!("stack frame depth {}", stack_frame_depth());
    fn print_depth2() {
        println!("stack frame depth {}", stack_frame_depth());
    }
    print_depth2();
}

pub fn main() {
    print_depths();
}
```

would print

```
stack frame depth 1
stack frame depth 2
```

I know `main` has callers so the particular numbers might be different.

I have tried [`stacker::remaining_stack`](https://docs.rs/stacker/0.1.13/stacker/fn.remaining_stack.html). However, that prints a count of bytes remaining in the stack. Since the arguments passed to a function affect the stack byte "height" then it is not possible to derive a simple function call "height". I want a count of the current function call height.

Comment: Question [Does Rust expose call stack depth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46011459/does-rust-expose-call-stack-depth) is not a duplicate of this. That regards checking stack for space left; not current function call depth.

Comment: I assert that the entire stack is a single stack frame, and therefore implement this as `fn stack_frame_depth() -> u64 { 1 }`. I'd be interested to know how you intend to prove me wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If, having noted all the caveats in [Peter Hall's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69141478/how-to-get-the-current-stack-frame-depth-in-rust#69141564), it is still desirable to obtain the *actual* stack depth, consider [`backtrace::Backtrace`](https://docs.rs/backtrace/0.3.61/backtrace/struct.Backtrace.html):

```rust
#[inline]
fn stack_frame_depth() -> usize {
    Backtrace::new_unresolved().frames().len()
}
```

[See it on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e4fe6057596fc9e434872b53ad225dac).

If you want to avoid the allocation involved in instantiating a `Backtrace`, consider [`backtrace::trace`](https://docs.rs/backtrace/0.3.61/backtrace/fn.trace.html) instead:

```rust
#[inline]
fn stack_frame_depth() -> usize {
    let mut depth = 0;
    backtrace::trace(|_| {
        depth += 1;
        true
    });
    depth
}
```

Both of the above approaches require `std` for thread-safety, however.  If your crate is `no_std` and/or you are ensuring synchronization some other way, there's [`backtrace::trace_unsynchronized`](https://docs.rs/backtrace/0.3.61/backtrace/fn.trace_unsynchronized.html).

Comment: I hadn't come across this crate before. As you say, it is quite limited though. Running that code in playground gives `14, 15` in a debug build and `9, 9` in release.

Comment: Which you can "fix" by annotating the functions with `#[inline(never)]`.

Comment: @PeterHall: You mean, hint to the compiler that you'd *like* for it to fix...

Comment: yes exactly. That's why I put the word in ""

Comment: To handle the unpredictable initial stack frame depth [I set a `static` global value once in `pub fn main()` to the current stack frame depth. Later I take the difference of the static variable and the current stack frame depth](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2d870ad0b835ffc8499f7a16b1c424ec). This works great! Thanks!

Comment: @JamesThomasMoon: what are you using this for?  I’m struggling to think of ways in which this could be useful.

Comment: @eggyal It's [a crude but useful tracing helper that indents debugging printing](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d72f26009871857b5f17ca8858d35bfe). I find the indentation very helpful for skimming through a program run's "debug print history" and verifying overall behavior, not too dissimilar from a flame graph's visual representation.  In my actual program, I'm using [`debug_eprintln`](https://docs.rs/debug_print/1.0.0/debug_print/index.html) so it doesn't affect `--release` builds.

Comment: @JamesThomasMoon: Are you aware of the [tracing](https://crates.io/crates/tracing) crate?

Comment: @eggyal `tracing` looks powerful! But also more complex and setup-heavy than I'd like at this time. Maybe I'll consider `tracing` in the future. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @eggyal I made a little crate `si_trace_print` based on this Answer.  [The docs link to this Answer](https://github.com/jtmoon79/si_trace_print/blob/f79715db4a582f47fbaed21697c0348fa55b4cfd/src/stack.rs#L30-L35).

Answer (score 6):

After optimisations, the code that actually runs is very unlikely to resemble in any way the structure of functions that you originally wrote.

If Rust exposed a function to give you the number of call frames on the stack, the number would vary hugely, depending on optimisation settings and the exact contents of these functions. For example, adding a debug print statement could change if it is inlined or not. The number could be different depending on if the build is debug or release, if lto is enabled or even if you upgraded to a newer compiler.

In order to accurately track the number of function calls, corresponding to functions in your source code, the compiler would need to add a counter increment to every function body, breaking Rust's promise of zero cost abstraction.

You could write a macro for declaring functions, that increments a counter at the start of each function and decrements it at the end. Then you pay for what you use. For example, [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=709ccf9b736ca02df02b82db37d1ebf3) is a simplified (doesn't support generics) declarative macro which does this. A procedural macro would be better for something like this, and you could define it to be called as an attribute instead.